Proper eslint configuration under NextJS 15
I just upgrade to NextJS 15.0.1, eslint 9.13.0, @next/eslint-plugin-next 15.0.1
I can't figure out how to get rid of this error during a build:
The Next.js plugin was not detected in your ESLint configuration. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#migrating-existing-config
The instructions at the provided URL are for the old eslintrc configuration format.
Any tips?
My eslint.config.mjs is as follows:
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";
import pluginReact from "eslint-plugin-react";

export default [
  {files: ["**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,jsx,tsx}"]},
  {languageOptions: {globals: {...globals.browser, ...globals.node}}},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  pluginReact.configs.flat.recommended,
  {
    rules: {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
      "react/prop-types": "off",
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-object-type": "off", // remove
      "no-prototype-builtins": "off", // explore
      "no-unused-vars": "warn",
      "no-undef": "warn",
    },
  },
  {
    ignores: ["src/tools/"],
  },
];

I'm just trying to get rid of the warning.

Try this
import pluginNext from '@next/eslint-plugin-next'

export default defineConfig([
  {
    plugins: {
      '@next/next': pluginNext
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
    rules: {
      ...pluginNext.configs.recommended.rules
    }
  }
])


That's great!  Thank you!

This works for me (I tested with next 15.0.3 / eslint 9.14 / eslint-config-next 15.0.3)

eslint.config.mjs

import pluginNext from '@next/eslint-plugin-next';
import parser from '@typescript-eslint/parser'; // optional

export default [
  {
    name: 'ESLint Config - nextjs',
    languageOptions: {
      parser, // optional
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaFeatures: {
          jsx: true,
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      '@next/next': pluginNext,
    },
    files: ['**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    rules: {
      ...pluginNext.configs.recommended.rules,
      ...pluginNext.configs['core-web-vitals'].rules,
    },
  },
];


Works fine for the js project, thanks

improved fixes for import issues
import pluginNext from '@next/eslint-plugin-next';
import parser from '@typescript-eslint/parser';

/** @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config} */
const config = {
  languageOptions: {
    parser,
    parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2020,
      sourceType: 'module',
      ecmaFeatures: {
        jsx: true,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: {
    '@next/next': pluginNext,
  },
  rules: {
    ...pluginNext.configs.recommended.rules,
  },
};

export default config;

